# How to include header-libs to IDE (Visual Studio Code), imported by conan

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, include, conan

I have a CMake project, library range-v3 imported by conan. All builds and links ok.

When I open to edit the project with Visual Studio Code I have to point to the header locations and here is the problem.
In one hand I've got **"conanbuildinfo.cmake"** there I got **_INCLUDE_DIRS**,
but how can I set it in Visual Studio Code not using an absolute path?

I've already updated the C/C++ extension json and set up the include dir.
But it's ugly, I'm in need of a more elegant and convienient way.

> 1. conanfile.txt, imports don`t affect

```
[requires]
range-v3/0.5.0@ericniebler/stable


[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./bin
lib, *.dynlib* -> ./lib
lib, *.so -> ./lib

[generators]
cmake
```

> 2. Part of c/c++ extension JSON

```
{
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Linux",
"includePath": [
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"/home/myname/.conan/data/range-v3/0.5.0/ericniebler/stable/package/52137beddd093ee80959d89f66348c14a1589eb7/include"
],
```

No error messages with that, but it's just an ugly style.

Comment: There is not official Conan extension for VSC, only for VS. You can use vscode-cmake-tools extension, provided by Vector-of-Bool, which supports CMake commands. If you use conan_basic_setup in your CMake file, and running Conan install command, all other steps should be solved by CMake automatically.
https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/getting_started.html
https://gist.github.com/uilianries/485a08f0bcc301ae8382d99c8dda4290

Comment: Hm, seems out of the box no convenient decision, instead Qt Creator got my cmake+conan configuration and made right ways, for coding.
Nevertheless thanks for your advice and links.

Comment: I found that the standard conan example at https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html did work (after `mkdir build && cd build; conan install ..`). Initially intellisense wasn't working; however that resolved itself for unknown reasons (could have been switching between projects, could have been changing some default settings that were invalid types, or something else).